# Can jQuery be Integrated with XRegExp for Filtering Elements/Words?

Tags: jquery, regex, xregexp

## Question

Can jQuery integrate with xRegExp, or other regular expression libraries that support Unicode?

Such as,  **`\b(\p{L}+)\b/g`**

(perhaps overriding a prototype definition, etc)

1. To return elements based on the regex?
2. To jQuery.filter() based on another regex libray?
3. To split() words based on another library?
4. to .each() using another regex library?

## Context:

**Unicode tags, attributes, sentences:**

`<div id="FragmentText1">ncididunt ut εἶπεν πρὸς<div>`

`<div id="πρὸς_id">ncididunt ut εἶπεν πρὸς<div>`